# addiction modules drupal 7

Tags: module, drupal-7, dependencies, open-atrium

I'm using version 7 of Drupal and I'm adding additional modules, in particular the modules of Open Atrium.

When I add a module I have many required modules set to "missing" and I can't activate the module.

Can I install a module and automatically all dependent modules?

Alternatively I have to manually install more than 100 modules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use drush to download and enable modules.

Here you have all the info for installing drush: https://drupal.org/node/1791676

for example:

```
>drush dl views

Project views (7.x-3.7) downloaded to /var/www/drupal_7_test/sites/all/modules/views.                                                                                                               [success]
Project views contains 2 modules: views_ui, views.
```

this will download views module only, then you can enable it and if the module have declare dependencies, drush will download and enable it.

```
>drush en views

The following projects have unmet dependencies:
views requires ctools
Would you like to download them? (y/n): y
Project ctools (7.x-1.4) downloaded to /var/www/drupal_7_test/sites/all/modules/ctools.                                                                                                             [success]
Project ctools contains 10 modules: ctools_plugin_example, ctools_ajax_sample, bulk_export, ctools_custom_content, term_depth, stylizer, views_content, page_manager, ctools_access_ruleset, ctools.
The following extensions will be enabled: views, ctools
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
ctools was enabled successfully.                                                                                                                                                                    [ok]
views was enabled successfully.
```

Not all modules have declare such dependecies and you should install them manually but as you can see is an easy task with drush.